# Multiple uri occurrences in POST API platform

Tags: php, json, symfony, post, api-platform.com

The purpose is to relate the Order entity and the Product as An order could have multiple products and a product could belong to multiple orders

Here's my Order class

```php
class Order
{

//..........

/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="cart")
     *
     * @Groups({"admin:read", "admin:write"})
     */
    private $products;

//..........

}
```

Here's my Product class

```php
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @Groups({"admin:read","media_object_read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Groups({"admin:read", "admin:write","media_object_read"})
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message = "The product name should not blank"
     * )
     *
     */
    private $name;

//..........
```

When i try to post an order relationing several times the same uri, only one is written.

Here's a exemple:

[burpsuite screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZHuc.png)

As you can see i posted 2 times `api/products/1` but it appear only one time in the response.

Could you explain me how to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to create an order with a list of products, I think to best way to do that would be to quantify the products. In your example, if you want an order with 2 **product 1** you should have something like:

```json
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "/api/products/1",
      "quantity": 2
    }  
  ]
}
```

Hope it'll help!

Comment: Should i create a quantity field on produts table ?